# $\tan^{2}(\theta) + 1 = \sec^2(\theta)$ and $\cot^{2}(\theta) + 1 = \csc^{2}(\theta)$ are not trigonometric identities?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan^{2}(\theta) + 1 = \sec^{2}(\theta)$$ 
                  and
$$\cot^{2}(\theta) + 1 = \csc^{2}(\theta)$$

are trigonometric identities?????

As 1st equation is not true for $\theta$ equals to 90 Degree.

And 2nd equation is not true for $\theta$ equals to 0 Degree.

Is it true?

Means only $\sin^{2}(\theta) + \cos^{2}(\theta) = 1$ is trigonometric identity.

What are yours view on it.

Comment: Those relationships are identities in their domains of definition.

Comment: @Gurmeet Singh Both are identitites because these are also valid there what you have mentioned.

Comment: $$\tan^2\vartheta +1=\frac{\sin^2\vartheta}{\cos^2\vartheta}+\frac{\cos^2\vartheta}{\cos^2\vartheta}=\frac{1}{\cos^2\vartheta}=\sec^2\vartheta$$ is true whenever $\tan\vartheta\;\land\;\sec\vartheta$ are defined, as @MarkViola has already said.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am concerned,
a relation that is true
whenever everything in it
is defined
is a identity.

For example,
$x\cdot\dfrac1{x} = 1
$
is, by my definition,
an identity,
and those trig relations
are similarly
identities.